# Adding multiple nameservers

Tags: nameserver

I have hostinger subscription for domain and web hosting. But I made my website through Wix and their premium package allowed me to use their domain to host my site. Since the priority was to open my website I followed Wix's instructions and changed namesrvers in my hostinger account and everything worked fine. But now I want to add more people in the email domain provided by hostinger and hostinger wants me to point my nameserver to their servers. Can I not add multiple nameservers for different activities like website and email or etc?

Comment: I don't think so, in order to edit the zone you have to do it in the server who has authority over the domain.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What are the exact domains involved? It is unclear what "email domain" means in your context.